# Mute audio files for playback?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I got few audio files in my sequence editor, and I would like to mute them all temporarily. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first cut the audio clips by placing the time cursor at the right place, then hit <kbd>K</kbd>. This will separate the clip in two clips. Repeat the operation for the end.

Then, you can mute the **selected** (active) audio clip by clicking the little **eye icon** in the properties panel (to show it, press <kbd>N</kbd> when hovering the sequence editor, or click the little (+) button at the top right corner of the window):

[image]

Another method would be to animate (with keyframes) the "Volume" setting between values 0 (mute) and 1 (listen):

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont see eye icon on my blender, probably because I'm still useing 2.69 version, whatever I noticed that i can mute my audio files by decreasing volume to 0 but it's still takes a while to do that on every file. I would like to mute my all files by one click, and that's why sometimes blender is annyoing me, he dont have a options which could make work faster, It's excatly the same with obj groups when you can't select few objects and add them to one group, you need to do this one by one, anyway, thank you for reply, just I need to deal with it :)

Comment: Edit: Guys, I asked about it on a forum too and there is a way to mute all audio files by one click ! :) You can do this on time line, by clicking on "playback" and then "audio muted" thx one more time, bye ! :)

Comment: @arto The eye icon should be there in 2.69, but you need to select a strip to see it. Could you add the technique that worked for you as an answer? That way other people can find it more easily. Thanks :)

Comment: ofc ! here's the screen how to that =) Edit: I can't add image as Polosson did, so I will just leave a link.  http://send-picture.com/img-5347b280340ed.html

Comment: You just have to add another answer (button below).

Answer (score 5):

[image: mute audio files]

You were right. thx Polosson. :)

Step by step if you want to mute all audio files in your sequence editor:
1 Make your timeline visible
2 Click on Playback (You can find it on your timeline bar)
3 Choose "Audio muted" from the list and mark it.
If you want to back your audio audible, just unmark "Audio Muted"

Comment: Please include the text version of this answer. e.g. PLayback -> Audio Muted, something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could try "selecting by" - strip type and creating a meta strip of the audio strips. Then press H key to hide them (disable) to turn back on Alt H. This would allow you to choose the parts you want to hear/not hear.